# How to make a vectorlayer through of sentence SQL on PostGRES

Tags: postgis, postgresql, python-2.7

How do I create a vectorlayer to through SQL on PostGiS on Python 2.7. I is working with QGIS 1.8 and I needed create a vectorLayer through SQL on PostGIS.

Answer (score 1):

You could either do it directly in PostGIS by using PgAdmin and the SQL window there or if you must do it via a dialog in QGIS, then open the DBManager plugin and use the SQL window in that dialog.